# What is [Symbol(kHeaders)] and how do I parse it as headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs

I am having trouble parsing the header retrieved from graphql's context, what I would like to do is to basically forward the headers from the request into the response

My gateway:

```
GraphQLModule.forRootAsync<ApolloGatewayDriverConfig>({
    driver: ApolloGatewayDriver,
    inject: [ConfigService],
    useFactory: async(configService: ConfigService) => ({
        server: {
            introspection: true,
            playground: true,
            cache: 'bounded'
        },
        gateway: {
            buildService: (url) => new CustomDataSource(url),
            supergraphSdl: ...
        }
    })
})
```

My CustomDataSource which should forward headers:

```
export class CustomDataSource  extends RemoteGraphQLDataSource {
    constructor(config: any) {
        super(config);
        this.fetcher = fetcher.defaults({
            maxSockets: Infinity,
            strictSSL: false,
            retry: false,
        })
    }

    willSendRequest({context, request }) {
        console.log('context', context.req); // <---- here
        request.http?.headers.set('authorization', context.req.authorization);
    }
}
```

My issue now is that the context.req.headers do not exist when it should and logging it out gives me headers in a different name as kHeaders instead which I am unsure of how to parse this.

context.req:

```
{
  ...,
  ...,
  [Symbol(kHeaders)]: {
    authorization: 'abcdefg'
  }
}
```

I tried something like context.req['Symbol(kHeaders)'] which returns me cannot read properties, would like to know why is my headers returned this way and how do I parse this

Comment: The headers should be in `context` object. Have you tried to log `context.authorization`?

Comment: yeee, it's weird the whole section for the normal header is gone, im only left with this symbol and rawheader, im using rawheader as a workaround now

Comment: Encountering the same problem after upgrading to node v16/v18. In node v14 the header was available in the context but with the update it isn't. Did you solve this?

Comment: i believed i used the rawHeaders as a work around and wrote a util to parse it into object format, then later app was refactored such that the stuff i needed are all in the authorization token which I got from context.authorization

Answer (score 0):

That is probably not the end game solution for your issue, but for other people like me trying to access values inside [Symbol(kHeaders)... You can access the properties inside [Symbol(kHeaders)] using req.get().

In your case it would be req.get('authorization')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The [nestjs `req`uest object](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-object) is the [expressjs `Request` object](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) is the [nodejs `IncomingMessage` object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) which has [`.headers`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#messageheaders) and [`.rawHeaders`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#messagerawheaders) properties. Do not try to access the internal symbol-keyed property.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the headers by looking up all the symbols for the property, and then selecting the symbol by matching its string representation, like this:

```
const headerSymbol = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(request)
                       .find((s) => s.toString() === 'Symbol(kOutHeaders)');
const requestHeaders = request[headerSymbol];
```